# Can I develop python code in Windows 7 with virtualenv in Ubuntu 16.04 on VMware

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, vmware

For personal reasons, I should develop python script with Pycharm on Windows 7. 
But as you know, installing and configuring pip and virtualenv in windows is very very difficult. although using pycharm, virtualenv didn't work properly.

So I am looking for the way that use virtualenv in Ubuntu 16.04 on VMware Workstation.

Is it possible? If so, How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is too broad and unclear. You see if you have a Ubuntu installation rest assured: anything you can do with python... Will work on Ubuntu. So just try it. Beyond that: if you can upgrade to w10, as that has an Ubuntu "inside" you will find that many more "Linux like" things can be done on such a Windows 10 system.

Comment: Just install Ubuntu in Virtualbox... And then open a shell to access Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually easily create virtual environments on Windows using the Anaconda distribution of Python. You can use the CLI to create the environment

```
conda create --name TestEnv python=3.5
```

and then just activate it in the command line.

```
activate TestEnv
```

Below is a link to the Anaconda environment management docs.

[Anaconda Docs](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html)

Comment: Anaconda is great! Thank you.